# Defining dimensions in Kotlin DSL for gradle

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm converting my `build.gradle` to Kotlin DSL. I have 2 build flavors in the app, and I can't figure out how to set the dimension for the flavors:

```
flavorDimensions("type")

productFlavors {
    create("free") {
        buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_DONATE", false.toString())
        dimension = "type"
    }
    create("donate") {
        buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_DONATE", true.toString())
        dimension = "type"
    }
}
```

the `dimension = "type"` part is failing; how do you set the dimension to each flavor?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Use setDimension("type")

```kotlin
flavorDimensions.add("type")

productFlavors {
    create("free") {
        buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_DONATE", false.toString())
        setDimension("type")
    }
  
    create("donate") {
        buildConfigField("boolean", "IS_DONATE", true.toString())
        setDimension("type")
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this is awkward, I had tried that, and it was showing in red, as if it was an error, but I just tried again, and now it flies.

Comment: @Francesc wasn't it so because gradle needed to resync and the project needed to rebuild? same thing as with annotations and generated code (e.g. dagger)

Comment: flavorDimensions was deprecated. you should use flavorDimensions.add

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a newer gradle version with kotlin script:

```
flavorDimensions.add("type")
    
productFlavors {
    create("free") {
        dimension = "type"
        buildConfigField(...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the answer of [Shweta Chauhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6021469/shweta-chauhan), in new versions of Gradle, `setDimension("type")` is deprecated.

You should use `dimension("type")` instead.